# React-Native and playing music from the Soundcloud API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, soundcloud

I am just getting started with React-Native. Does anyone have any experience getting soundcloud songs to play?  I have tried an iframe webview, but I need the song to be playing while surfing through the app.  The webview only allows for me to play something while the webview is open.

I am thinking the best way to do this would be to have an invisible iframe webview that never gets refreshed.  Is this possible?

I've also tried using the react-native-sound package, however I can't use that to stream from the soundcloud Stream URL.

Does anyone have any ideas/worked with this before?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this](https://github.com/fraserxu/soundredux-native)? He has also written a blog post on the subject – you can find the link in the README.

Comment: @villeaka I have.  Problem is he's using the react-native-player for processing his soundcloud links which only has android support right now. I am hoping to do this on iOS

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a more native implementation.

There is an Objetive C/Cocoa (iOS) wrapper available that supports the audio streaming. https://github.com/soundcloud/cocoa-api-wrapper

There is also an Android one (it looks like support was discontinued, but still should work) https://github.com/soundcloud/java-api-wrapper

You can wrap those using Native Modules and let the OS handle the playing of the audio. It will work better than some WebView based circumvention.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion.

Use this library for soundcloud api in react-native.

https://github.com/nhayflick/ReactNativeMusic

Comment: Thanks! But this is **only for iOS**